# MySQL wont start with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

I have installed XAMPP on my Ubuntu 14.04 and everything works but not MySQL. MySQL is installed and works just fine with workbench but not when I try to reach it with a installation of Magento.

Strange thing is that with XAMPP app it shows MySQL as stopped but I can reach it with workbench. I have tried to restart MySQL both through terminal and XAMPP app but that did not work. I know my MySQL user name and password so that can not be the issue.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I think you have two MYSql's installed and that they seem to run on the same port. you could either change the port or remove that mysql you start from terminal... What Error do you get when attempting to start MYSQL from XXAMP?

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that the preinstalled MySQL conflicted with the MySQL from xampp. Be removing the preinstalled MySQL everything works just fine.